# How to connect Paypal Card Reader with Native iOS App

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I am creating a native iOS app. I want to receive the payment via the Paypal Chip or Card Reader.

Here is scenario 
App will create multiple invoices. So when user want to pay for the specific invoice he/she swipe the card on the reader and when the payment processed successfully the invoice will be closed in app and set as paid. So i can save all of paid invoices record in my DB.

How to implement it guide me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SDK for this which is PayPal Here SDK. You can integrate the SDK with your application to accept credit card payment using the PayPal Chip or PayPal Card Reader. For more information, please refer to the documentation on PayPal Developer site:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/